# Laravel controller's create function not saving all data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save this "code" attributes into my codes table along with the "gift_card_id", but only the first one is saved.

- When I call the dd($giftCard), it shows me the model info itself, not
  an object from it. and when I dd($giftCard->id), it gives me null.
- When I add ($id) to my function parameters "public function generateCodes(Request $request, GiftCard $giftCard, $id)", and change the create function to "$giftCard->codes()->create(['code' => $code, 'gift_card_id' => $id]);"
  and call dd($id), it shows the right id.

In both of the above, the data get stored excpt the "gift_card_id".

web.php

```
Route::post('gift-cards/{giftcard}/add-codes', 'GiftCardController@generateCodes')->name('gift-cards.generateCodes');
```

GiftCardController.php

```
public function generateCodes(Request $request, GiftCard $giftCard) {

    $request->validate([
        'amount' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ]);

    if ($request->input('amount') > 0) {
        do {
            $codes = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < $request->input('amount'); $i++) {
                $codes[] = (string)mt_rand(pow(10, 10), pow(10, 11) - 1);
            }

            $codesUnique = Code::whereIn('code', $codes)->count() == 0;
        } while (!$codesUnique);

        foreach ($codes as $code) {
            // dd($id);
            $giftCard->codes()->create(['code' => $code]);
        }
    }
```

View.blade.php

```
 @foreach($giftCards as $key => $giftcard)
    <tr data-entry-id="{{ $giftcard->id }}">
        <td> {{ $giftcard->name ?? '' }}  </td>
        <td> {{ $giftcard->price ?? '' }} </td>
        <td> {{ $giftcard->codes_count ?? '' }} </td>
        @can('gift_card_create')
          <td>
            <form action="{{route('gift-cards.generateCodes', $giftcard->id)}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
               <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" required>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-success ml-2" value="Generate">
             </form>
            </td>
         @endcan
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: show your route definition

Comment: `giftcard != giftCard` ... you need to have the type hinted parameter on the route action match the route parameter if you want implicit route model binding to happen, otherwise you are just getting dependency injection (which will give you an empty non-existing model instance)

Comment: Thank u so much for ur answer, that was the problem. I have been working for 10 hours straight and couldn't see the difference in typing the word. It's working fine now. thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the type-hinted parameter name on the route action match the name of the route parameter if you want Explicit Route Model Binding to take place. If you don't match these you are just defining dependencies that the method needs which would cause Dependency Injection to happen. You can change the route parameter name or the name of the parameter for the method so they match:

```
Route::post('gift-cards/{giftCard}/add-codes', ...);
```